# PackageManage checkSignatures only working one way

Tags: android

I'm writing an "unlocker" app to unlock premium features of my app, and am using PackageManager.checkSignatures to:
(a) Check that the unlocker app is installed (from the MainActivity of the main app)
(b) Check whether the main app is installed (from the MainActivity of the unlocker app). 
My problem is that while check (a) succeeds, check (b) does not - checkSignatures returns a value of -4.

The code for (a) (in the MainActivity of com.myorg.myname.myapp) is:

```
final PackageManager pkgMgr = this.getPackageManager();
final int sigMatch =
        pkgMgr.checkSignatures(getApplicationContext().getPackageName(),
                "com.myorg.myname.myappunlocker");
if (sigMatch == PackageManager.SIGNATURE_MATCH) {
    // All OK
```

The code for (b) (in the MainActivity of com.myorg.myname.myappunlocker) is:

```
final PackageManager pkgMgr = getPackageManager();
final int sigMatch = pkgMgr.checkSignatures(this.getPackageName(),
        "com.myorg.myname.myapp");
if (sigMatch == PackageManager.SIGNATURE_MATCH) {
    //All is OK
```

Both apps have been signed from the same keystore.

Can anyone tell me why check (b) fails, when both packages are installed?

Comment: Why does the unlocker app need to check if the main app is installed? Isn't checking signatures from one side enough?

Comment: It's so that I can give an appropriate warning message if a user installs and runs the  unlocker app without installing the main app